# URL encoding issue for path param which has '/'

Tags: java, urlencode

I have an issue while encoding an URL. My url might contain a path param which can include a slash "/". I need to send this path param to an external API. This is always encrypted+Encoded. But i have issues encoding '/'. Everything else is encoding except '/'.

Example:

```
https://url.com/bdvchewcbwj%2Fhbsdwhjkbq%3D
```

In the above example the path param without encoded is :

```
bdvchewcbwj/hbsdwhjkbq=
```

When i encode the above path param i am expecting the url as :

```
https://url.com/bdvchewcbwj%2Fhbsdwhjkbq%3D
```

but the result is :

```
bdvchewcbwj/hbsdwhjkb%3D
```

Input:

```
https://url.com/bdvchewcbwj/hbsdwhjkbq%3D
```

Output Expected:

```
https://url.com/bdvchewcbwj%2Fhbsdwhjkbq%3D
```

I am using okHttp client to create the request. Is there any library that just encodes the unencoded characters leaving already encoded characters?

Answer (score 1):

How do you encode a parameter? For me

```
URLEncoder.encode("bdvchewcbwj/hbsdwhjkbq=","UTF-8");
```

works as expected and the result is

```
bdvchewcbwj%2Fhbsdwhjkbq%3D
```

Comment: no.Thats not what i am trying to encode. you are trying to encode a string which doesnt have already encoded values. In my case the last '=' is already encoded and the '/' remains unencoded.  URLEncoder.encode("bdvchewcbwj/hbsdwhjkbq%3D","UTF-8"); to "bdvchewcbwj%2Fhbsdwhjkbq%3D" is what i need

Comment: It's completely unclear from the question. >.. _the above example_: `bdvchewcbwj/hbsdwhjkbq=`, _When i encode the above path param i am expecting the url as_ :`bdvchewcbwj%2Fhbsdwhjkbq%3D`, _but the result is_: `bdvchewcbwj/hbsdwhjkb%3D`

Comment: _In my case the last '=' is already encoded and the '/' remains unencoded_ how did you achieve that? I think that is a main problem then.  If `bdvchewcbwj/hbsdwhjkbq=` is a solid param, not the result of a concatenation or something like this, then it should be encoded in full or not encoded at all

Comment: @ging I’m confused.  Nowhere in your question do you state that you have an input string in which some but not all unsafe characters are URL-encoded.

Comment: @VGR YuriyTsarkov updated the question with expected input and output.

Comment: @ging you said _the param without encoded is_ `bdvchewcbwj/hbsdwhjkbq=`, _the input is_ `bdvchewcbwj/hbsdwhjkb%3D`, and _expected output is_ `bdvchewcbwj%2Fhbsdwhjkbq%3D`. How did you get from the first one to the second one? What's wrong with an answer that get you from the first one directly to your expected output skipping the unnecessary middle case?

Comment: @RickyMo I am just trying to explain there that the decoded string is "bdvchewcbwj/hbsdwhjkbq=" . But when i try to encode in the program i have the string like "bdvchewcbwj/hbsdwhjkb%3D" So when i try to encode this, '/' is successfully encoded but the last '=' is double encoded. I am just trying to eliminate the encoding of already encoded characters.

Comment: @ging You can just let it double encoded and decode twice when you try to decode. Not sure how did you get the weird partly encoded string in the first place but if you did, this is as best you can do. The source which generates the partly encoded string should be the one responsible to fix the problem.

Comment: @RickyMo I need the whole string just once encoded. So i am looking for library that will just encode the unecoded characters and leaving the characters which are already encoded.

Comment: @ging You can first decode the input once. Then encode it once.